# how to run multiple builds on a single Job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have a script to run to which i give multiple parameters in a loop, it takes each parameter completes the cycle and then the next one.

I need to run this on Jenkins, is there any option that i can run multiple builds on a single job ? I mean each parameter should be a single build and all the builds should run in queue not parallel.

Comment: [Matrix Project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin)

Comment: @tkausl could you please provide any documentation link for this ?? 
jenkins wiki is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two options :

1.) In my case i use a shell script and csv file as an input to it. So i wrote a simple groovy script for getting the inputs from csv file. Then i used parameterized plugin to run the script

2.) In case if you want to see the workflow on GUI you can go for pipeline